# Powershell script show count of subfolders

Tags: powershell

I'm going around in circles trying to run a powershell script which returns the sub-folder count of sub-folders in my root directory.

E.g. Root directory C:\temp
Subfolders are C:\temp\1 and C:\temp\2 and each have x subfolders

I want to see the count of subfolders in C:\temp\1 and C:\temp\2 and if they are under C:\temp\1 or C:\temp\2.

So far I can only get a total subfolder count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple to do:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Directory `
| Select-Object @{n='FullName';e={$_.FullName}},@{n='SubFolderCount';e={(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -Directory).Count}} `
| Format-Table -Autosize;
```